# Can ECDSA signature signing and verification process replaces password hashed based login system?

Tags: elliptic-curves, authentication, passwords, dsa, password-hashing

ECDSA or DSA in general was to sign a message or data using private key and verify it using public key, if the attacker/imposter doesn't have the private key then they couldn't sign the message properly.

If ECDSA private key was kept private, can the signature verification of ECDSA be used for user to login into a system ? Rather than a password hashed based login approach ?

Comment: SSH already does this. I'll leave room for new members to provide more thorough answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is secure provided the message to be signed is unique on each login to prevent replay attacks.  Usually that's done with either a random challenge or the signature over a shared secret.

In fact, SSH does this already with ECDSA keys: the two sides agree on a shared secret, which is hashed, and the client signs the hashed secret and some other data to verify that it's allowed to log in.  MariaDB also does a similar thing by deriving an Ed25519 key (which isn't exactly ECDSA, but is similar) and using that to sign a random challenge (although it doesn't necessarily derive this key in a secure way).

Similarly, most FIDO2 and WebAuthn two-factor authentication devices, such as YubiKeys, use this approach.  You could also use TLS client certs that are ECDSA, which is another approach used in some environments.

This could be used for any type of login, including websites, but it is less common there because people don't expect to carry a key around with them everywhere and frequently log into websites from different computers, so it's practically inconvenient.  But ignoring the practical problems, this is secure if implemented correctly.

Comment: I recently think of user keep requesting random data/message to be signed with .. but what do you mean by "random challenge" ? I am using a CA signed RSA 4096 bits key certificate(from a source it stated it's equivalent to 128 bits of AES key in terms of strength).

Comment: I would like to know given in such case: 
cuz right now what i have in my mind was to create an ephemeral shared secret[combination of client ECDSA/ED25519 + ECDH(X25519) through libsodium every web api session] with 1 built in TLS/SSL + Libsodium ephemeral session upon registering/login/other activities

Comment: is this necessary or too much of a work ?

Comment: By "random challenge", I mean something like a 128-bit random value presented by the server on login that the client must sign to log in. I would say unless you have a specific threat model that requires a key-based approach, sending a plaintext password over TLS is probably fine.

Comment: Is the random challenge necessary needs to be 128 bit random value ? or it can be more than 128 bit ? Do I need to have passwords hashed based login mechanism too ?

Comment: There're things in which I don't want to happen here, data leakage do happens a lot in real world, even if passwords based login mechanism hashes the passwords properly through PBKDF2 or Argon or any proven cryptographic library, hashes do get to dump out on the dark web ... who knows what those hashes are? it could be valuable password to emails ? or bank accounts

Comment: So I will really like to avoid such things from happening that's why i try to think of a better approach because the application is api based rather than web pages based

Comment: Let me get this correctly:
1. Client generates their own ECDSA/ED25519 keys and sends the pub part to server
2. Upon login, they will be presented by random value or challenge to sign, then they sends the signed version to server
3. The server then do verification if it is okay then let them in 

Is this overall steps correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the approach you can use.  And the random value can be larger than 128 bits if you want.

Comment: As an extra information, is there any other forms of cryptographic authentication ? or currently there's only these 2 ?

Comment: Yes, there are other forms, but this comment field is too small to contain a suitable answer.  If you ask another question, someone will probably answer it.